# How to create an annotated tag with an empty message in Magit?

Tags: magit

### Objective

Create an annotated tag with an empty message, as would be created with the following command.

```
$ git tag --annotate epic-tag --message=""
```

### Attempts

1. Create it with `M-x magit-tag<RET> -a t tag-name<RET> <RET> C-c C-c`. This does not work, because git interprets no message specified interactively as don't create tag, resulting in the following in the magit-process buffer.

```
...
git … tag --annotate tag-name master
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
Waiting for Emacs...
fatal: no tag message?
```

2. Add argument `--message=` to `magit-tag`. I added a `--message=` argument to `magit-tag`(see [branch](https://github.com/olav35/magit/tree/argument/--message%3D) or [patch](https://github.com/olav35/magit/commit/0f2e5a50189486f126be1c3cfddccc327281e453.patch)), but when I try using my argument with an empty value it interprets it as cancelling the argument. Using '' or "" as a value literally uses '' or "" for the tag message.
3. Add a "virtual argument" `-e` that adds `--message=''` to the command. That also used '' as a literal tag message. See [branch](https://github.com/olav35/magit) or [patch](https://github.com/olav35/magit/commit/3a2a559d4db18b7be15b1aeb135b0b2db5f77875.patch).

### Anti-solutions

- Use lightweight tags. The tags must be annotated because they are meant for release*.

* Annotated tags are meant for release while lightweight tags are meant for private or temporary object labels. - GIT-TAG(1)

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

I updated my transient argument to accept empty values and now it works. [commit](https://github.com/olav35/magit/commit/d5f70d24d29d7500df291f06a30ae4c8745bae88) [patch](https://github.com/olav35/magit/commit/d5f70d24d29d7500df291f06a30ae4c8745bae88.patch)

### Update

Instead of customising Magit itself, one can add the argument to your personal configuration. Add the following code to your configuration to add an argument `-m`, to `magit-tag`, that accepts a optionally-empty message string.

```
(transient-define-argument magit-tag:--message ()
  :description "Use message"
  :class 'transient-option
  :shortarg "-m"
  :argument "--message="
  ;; Empty (annotated)tag messages must be permitted because it is
  ;; impossible to create them interactively.
  :allow-empty t)
(transient-append-suffix
  'magit-tag
  "-u"
  '(magit-tag:--message)))
```

Comment: You should open an [issue/pull request with magit](https://github.com/magit/magit) and see if they will accept your patch.

Comment: Hey, sorry for deleting my comment. I ended up not writing tests cases because looking at Magit's test suite I was unsure if it was appropriate to test it. Either way the pr is at https://github.com/magit/magit/pull/4247.

Comment: The pr was rejected, but kyleam suggested me a way to add the argument from a personal configuration instead of from the magit source. I will ~write another~ update my answer.